# WordPress thumbnail ID as thumbnail size

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<img class="icona" src="<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) , array(85, 85 ) , false, ''); echo $src[0]; ?>" />
```

I'm trying to get the "thumbnail" size src for the image. Instead with `array(85, 85 )` I just get it with `width` and `height` tags set to `85px` (but the image src can be 200000x200000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your functions.php add the wp function add_image_size('newimage', width, height, true)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

In your theme file:

**get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'newimage')** or **the_post_thumbnail('newimage')**

if you're images have already been added you'll have to regenerate your thumbnails. Use the plugin regenerate thumbnails to do this. If you haven't added the images yet than you should be good to go.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll try soon, thanks!! So I was getting the original image src because I wasn't requesting one of the available sizes? If I used array(150,150) - the size of the thumbnail size) - I would get the 150x150 src?